# How do i add a "soft" line break to a textview text

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, line-breaks

i'm trying to add a dynamic value to add to a textview, but i'm having trouble to define the line breaks

Currently it behaves like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing **Dynamic** 

**Word** elit, sed do
```

But i'd like it to keep the dynamic words together, like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing

**Dynamic** **Word** elit, sed do
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Line breaks are ```\n``` on strings or ```<br/>``` if you using Html.fromText() or use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#getTextBounds(java.lang.String,%2520int,%2520int,%2520android.graphics.Rect) and measure and align text as you wish

Comment: The value is dynamic, i don't know before hand where the line break should go